# Reverse the numbering order for ordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have the numbering of the ordered list in descending order. live example here:

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ad5dkgz7/1/)

But instead of having the counte span multiple ol, I would like the counter to reset after each ol.

So, the desired result for the live demo would be:

```
[3] 1
[2] 2
[1] 3

[2] 4
[1] 5
```

Does anyone have an idea how to modify the code from the live demo (or know a better solution that is supported by most browsers) to have the above behavior?

Also, is there a way to make the [ ] "copyable" with copy-paste to Word docs or any open source alternative? Because for the above example it interprets only the numbers without the square parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the **`counter-reset`** value for each **`ol`** is equal to the **`number of child + 1`**

```js
var ol_elements = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");
//console.log(ol_elements[0].children.length)
for (var i = 0; i < ol_elements.length; i++) {
  ol_elements[i].setAttribute('style', 'counter-reset: item ' + (ol_elements[i].children.length + 1));
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ol>li {
  counter-increment: item -1;
}

ol>li:before {
  content: "[" counter(item) "]";
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <ol>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Regarding the [ ], is there a way to make them copyable to documents? I'm thinking to make a button with a function that would open another window that has the printed version of the ol so that It will be easier to copy paste the information exactly how is on the website. Is this the right way to go?

Comment: How are your copying the things

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS counters to achieve that. Note that I am applying a :before pseudo-element to the li which displays the count.

Note the counter reset is set onto the ol element - that mean the count will resent with each instance of an ol so you don't need to bkeep track of the number of lists you have or the number of li's each list has. You can alse set it to count nested  lists wiithin the li's as well and display those as 1.1, 1.2 etc.

You can set the count to start again on each ol.... and you can have different counts and displays for different lists. So you can definitely structure them how you want.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

UPDATE - based on the nice answer from @Bhuwan Bhatt - I have added a javascript only version of the setting on the counter via querySelectorAll - used twice - first to get all the ols in the document and then within each ol to get the number of li's of that ol.

Then simply setting the counter to the lengt of the li's (+1 to due to the zero indexation of the li's)

```js
var lists = document.querySelectorAll('ol');
var listsLength = lists.length;

for(i=0;i<listsLength;i++) {
 var lis= lists[i].querySelectorAll('li');
 var lisLength = lis.length +1;
 lists[i].style.counterReset= 'section '+ lisLength;
}
```

```css
ol {
  list-style:none;
  padding-left:0;
  counter-reset: section ; /* Creates a new instance of the
                                section counter with each ul
                                 element - count set to 4 
                                 because of zero indexing of the list */
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section -1;   /* Using a negative number 
                                    to decrement the count */
  
  content: counter(section);  /* Display the count as :before element */
  margin-right:15px;  /* provide a margin between the ount and the li */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
 </ol>
 
 <ol>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
 </ol>
 
 <ol>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
 </ol>
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that I would like to not have to worry about keeping the track of the length of the list, because i would have many ordered lists with hundreds of items. That's why I would like to count them automatically.

Comment: Hi @AMayer - do some research on the css counters - they are awesome... and you can set the count to start again on each ol.... and you can have different counts and displays for different lists. So you can definitely structure them how you want.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

Comment: I see, but to use it I would need to know how many elements are in the list i.e (counter-reset: section 4). I tried avoiding this because there are many lists that I have to do with different lengths so it would be pretty hard to update the code each time I add another item in the lists.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that rely on flex and `column-reverse` value of column direction. This value will allow you to reverse the list and thus reverse the number but this will also reverse the data, so you can add a small jQuery code to put them back to initial order:

```js
$('ol.reverse').each(function() {
  $(this).append($(this).children('li').get().reverse());
})
```

```css
ol.reverse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="reverse">
  <li>aa</li>
  <li>ab</li>
  <li>ac</li>
</ol>

<ol class="reverse">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>bb</li>
  <li>cccc</li>
  <li>ddddd</li>
</ol>


<ol>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>bb</li>
  <li>cccc</li>
  <li>ddddd</li>
</ol>
```